# Splitting database table for performance?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, innodb

I have one MySQL innodb table storing data for my web service that is heavily used. I am wondering if splitting it into two tables(with identical schema) and having my web service balance load between the two tables offer any performance benefits if they are still sitting on the same database server?

Update: db inserts are slow and there’s an enum column called “type” that we can potentially use to split one table into multiple tables with different types

Thanks!

Comment: You can try the split and see, but I suspect you would need separate database servers to see a throughput improvement.

Comment: Probably not, because the queries running on the same MySQL instance will still be competing for the same resources. But it depends on the query and the cause of the current performance issue. Any optimization strategy must be tailored to the specific query you want to optimize.

Comment: Investigate [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html), and especially [Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably no noticeable benefit.

Please elaborate on "heavily used":

- If there are slow queries; let's see some of them; maybe they can be sped up.
- Your thought about "horizontal partitioning" (even with the builtin `PARTITION`) is *very* unlikely to help performance.
- If you have columns like "like_count" and/or "view_count", and these are frequently updated by one (thereby leading to "heavily used"), then there *may* be an excuse for pulling them out into a separate table.  This is "vertical partitioning".
- When a site becomes *really* busy (thousands of queries per second), "sharding" may be necessary.  This involves moving some 'users' to other servers.  This adds quite a bit of complexity to your application.

My point is that there is help for your system, but not necessarily the technique you are asking about.

Comment: I’m sorry for not providing enough details. I updated my question. Basically db inserts are slow since there can be many people inserting at the same time. There’s an enum column called “type” in the table that we can use to split the one table into separate independent tables with different types

Comment: @Jessica - "At the same time" is a common mis-phrasing.  Please provide something like "number of rows inserted per second".  Also provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @Jessica -  As for "type", how many different types?  What percentage of the inserts is into the most common type?  (The most popular 'type' will become the bottleneck; I am fishing for whether the proposed split will not help much.)